# Displaying which list item was clicked

Tags: javascript, events, closures, listener

I've been trying to wrap my head around closures in Javascript and how things are executed (or rather - in which order they are executed).

Here is my example: lets say I have an unordered list of items and when I click on one of them I want to print out which item was clicked. I know the solution but I don't understand why it works the way it works. So below im gonna post a few variations of my code and give my thoughts on how I believe it works. I want someone to comment on that. If possible, use as less jargon as possible. Imagine you're talking to a 5 year old.

**First example**
https://jsfiddle.net/wLpcpa5q/

My HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
<span id="span"></span>
```

JS:

```
var items = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var span = document.getElementById('span');

function clickHandler() {

    function changeHTML() {
        span.innerHTML = ('item ' + i + ' was clicked');
    }

    for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
        items[i].addEventListener("click", changeHTML);
    } 
}
clickHandler();
```

If I run it I will always get 'Item 5 was clicked' no matter which item I clicked on. I believe it happens because program's flow goes like this:

1. The loop goes through all the list items and adds an event listener to them. `changeHTML` isn't called yet because it's a reference to that function (no `()` at the end).
2. When `i = 5` the loop ends and program is awaiting for a click.
3. When a click happens `changeHTML` is called at which point `i = 5` no matter which list item is clicked.

Is that correct?

Moving on.

**Second example**
https://jsfiddle.net/wLpcpa5q/1/

Instead of `changeHTML` I use `changeHTML()` in the loop

```
for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
    items[i].addEventListener("click", changeHTML());
}
```

This prints out `item 4 was clicked` on its own without any clicks on list items. I'm confused about that. I suspect it prints itself because I added () at the end of the function so it's being called. Questions:

1. What is the order of execution here?
2. Why is `changeHTML()` called after the loop is finished? Why isn't it called after each iteration?
3. Why doesn't it wait for a click?

**Third example**
https://jsfiddle.net/wLpcpa5q/2/

Here is a working solution using a closure, a concept I don't really understand:

```
function clickHandler() {

    function wrap(i) {
        return function changeHTML() {
            span.innerHTML = 'item ' + (i + 1) + ' was clicked';
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
        items[i].addEventListener("click", wrap(i));
    }

 }

 clickHandler();
```

So, I don't understand why it works correctly this way.

1. Now inside of the loop I'm calling `wrap(i)` which kinda looks like second example because of (). But unlike second example the function is waiting for a click. Why is that?

2.I guess everything works because now I'm returning inner function `changeHTML` instead of just having it inside of `clickHandler`. But I don't understand what it means to return `changeHTML`.

3. So, again - I need someone to explain in which order things are executed here, which functions are called at which point in time, how it is related to the loop's iterations etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First exemple the loop finish before your click so i = 5
and changehtml is called only when you click

second exemple changehtml is called at every loop not at the click, you add an empty listener because the listener added is what changehtml will return and you dont return any function reference.

So why the third is working ?
Because this time you really add a function as listener, yes you return a function.
What's happen on a click :

- changeHTML is called, it look for the closest i declared, here i is an argument so he takes the 'i' that was passed as argument.

In the first case it can't worked because i is the same in clickHandler and the last value was 5.

In the last case you have created 5 different functions whitch have their own i